# Visual studio 12 and regular expressions error

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, visual-studio-2012

I am getting a strange error in VS2012.

I've got the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateEmail($email) {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if( !emailReg.test( $email ) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

This throws all sot of errors in the IDE, and in VS2010 used to run OK.

What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Would be helpful if you could specify what the "all sort of errors" were.

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Your provided code snippet is syntactically valid.

Comment: what kind of file is? `.html`? `.cshtml`? `.aspx`?

Comment: I know, syntactically is perfect! But the IDE doesn't like it. It says that is expecting a closing parenthesis ")".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me guess... are you using Razor (a cshtml page)? If so, this problem is caused because the IDE thinks that the part `@([\w-]+\.)` is a Razor expression and then, the javascript reg ex is looking for the missing parenthesis.
To fix this, you need to escape the `@` by using a `@@`
So your code will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateEmail($email) {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if( !emailReg.test( $email ) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Agustin, You guessed right! Thank you for the quick solution!